# Set Row ID to Increment so there are No Duplicates

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a table that has an ID that basically auto-increments. I have IDs up to 221. I have an add row function that adds rows and gives the row an ID based on how many rows there are. So if I delete a row and there are only 220 rows now, and once I add a row, the ID will be 221. However, there was already a 221 ID so no matter how many rows I delete, I want the ID to start at 222 and continue to go up from there. How would I do this?

HTML/PHP:

```
<table id="html_master">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td>Buyer ID</td>
    <td>POC Name</td>
    <td>POC Email</td>
    <td>POC Phone</td>
    <td>Edit/Delete</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="mr_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><button class="edit" name="edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="delRow" name="delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
</tbody>
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('html_master')">  
</table>
```

Javascript for adding row:

```
function addRow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = rowCount;

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell2.appendChild(element2);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    element3.type = "text";
    element3.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell3.appendChild(element3);

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var element4 = document.createElement("input");
    element4.type = "text";
    element4.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell4.appendChild(element4);

    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var element5 = document.createElement("input");
    element5.type = "text";
    element5.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell5.appendChild(element5);

    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    var element6 = document.createElement("input");
    element6.type = "text";
    element6.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell6.appendChild(element6);

    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
    var element7 = document.createElement("input");
    var element8 = document.createElement("input")
    element7.type = "button";
    element8.type = "button";
    element7.name="edit";
    element8.name="del"
    element7.value="Edit";
    element8.value="Delete";
    cell7.appendChild(element7);
    cell7.appendChild(element8);
}
```

Comment: Counter to your question: you are trying to solve this wrong. This should have NOTHING to do with JS/HTML and _maybe_ very little to do with PHP although it might also be nothing to do with it, either. Option 1: using PHP, instead of counting the columns, return the highest ID and add 1. That is your new ID. Option 2 (better) don't even bother with tracking the IDs, set the field to be autoincremented in your database and omit it when inserting.

Comment: Option 1 could be a problem because what if I delete 221...then 220 + 1 is 221 and I don't want that ID again...I need original row count (before any deletions) + 1 every time. Option 2 I am not quite following.

Comment: Option 2 - in your database you can set the ID column to have an autoincremented value. So instead of doing (roughly) `INSERT INTO myTable (ID, Name, Value)` you will instead do `INSERT INTO myTable (Name, Value)` and then the ID will be automatically populated for you by the database engine. It will keep track of what the number was and you don't have to bother with it.

Comment: On a separate note, if this is anything else but a hobby or a school project, then I strongly suggest never deleting anything from the database. It takes a single typo on a slight misstep from you OR the users and they can lose information. Anything stored in the database should be treated as very important and so, users could be using very important data. Instead do what's called a "lazy delete" - have another field essentially called "deleted" and if a record should be removed, just change the field to "true", instead.